# How to split input to create dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, split

So I'm a complete noob (as in I'm taking my first class rn), and I can't figure out how to do this.
I receive an input for a future dictionary key and values corresponding to said key in one line from the user like so:

```
fruitone = input("Please enter fruit name and values")
```

The input would be something like: apple 0.5 0.6 1.5 .
No commas or anything, just good ol' spaces.
Eventually, this becomes:

```
fruits = {'Apple': [0.5, 0.6, 1.5], 'Orange': [0.25, 0.4, 0.05]}
```

The issue I'm having is figuring out how to split this up so I can transform the input from one whole string into a string and multiple float objects that I can shove into a dictionary.
Please help?

Comment: For splitting into a list of strings there is a string method "split". Then you must convert all but first item to float. To convert one string to float, give it as argument to "float".

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_ ={}
strA = "apple 0.5 0.6 1.5"
strA = strA.split(' ')

dict_[strA[0]] = strA[1:]
```

O/p:
`{'apple': ['0.5', '0.6', '1.5']}`

Use your input() as the string strA each time.

`split` is extremely powerful. You should look up the Python documentation to understand more on how to exploit it.

Comment: Your answer should not be an image. This impacts not only searching but the OP as well. Please update your answer to include the relevant code.

Comment: I hear you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a dictionary like this

```
output = {}
latest_thing = "the current fruit"
for thing in fruitone.split(" "):
    if thing.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
        output[latest_thing].append(float(thing))
    else:
        output[thing] = []
        latest_thing = thing
```

assuming your input look like

apple 0.5 0.6 1.5 orange 0.25 0.4 0.05

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = {}


def get_inp():
    inp = input("Please enter fruit name and values: ")
    inp_values = inp.split(" ")
    if len(inp_values) == 4:
        key = inp_values[0]
        try:
            value = list(map(float, inp_values[1:]))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid")
            return
        fruits[key] = value
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        return


get_inp()
```

I'm assuming that you want each fruit to be associated with exactly 3 floats. Take input from the console and split it into a list of strings, dividing at every space. Exit if the resulting list is anything other than 4 elements long (for the fruit and 3 floats), then use `map()` to try to convert the number inputs to float values and then put them in a list, exiting if the conversion fails. Add the fruit string and resulting float list to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
fruitone = input("Please enter fruit name and values")
fruits = {}
for element in fruitone.split():
    if element.isalpha():
        fruits[element]=[]
        temp = element
    else:
        fruits[temp].append(float(element))
print(fruits)
```

Input : apple 0.5 0.6 1.5 orange 0.25 0.4 0.05
Output by above code : {'apple': [0.5, 0.6, 1.5], 'orange': [0.25, 0.4, 0.05]}

Comment: OMG Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Chron Accept any answer and upvote if the solution has helped.